# Select fields from multiple records in DBgrid to input in checklistbox?

Tags: delphi

I created a simple DB with Database desktop (Name, Age, Mail, Place etc.).
One name can include more Places (for example Steve: London, Bukarest, Ukraine).

I want to choose from these places in a new checklistbox or similar component. Is there any way to add these items from the DBGRID into the checklistbox to choose from?

I could not find any tool in the Data controls palette where i can select more items.

Comment: How are the associated locations stored in the database? 1:N (AdressID,LocationID)?

Comment: You should never try to populate controls from the DBGrid, but from the underlying dataset.

Comment: First result from Mr.Google "DBGrid MultiSelect": http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa032503a.htm

Answer (score 0):

dgMultiSelect in dbgrid-->Options allows users to select more than one row.

IIRC it returns bookmarks which are not the easiest thing to work with :(